# Can't see list of available job positions when logged in

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

This has been going on for some time now, I thought it was a bug but apparently not.
While browsing a Q/A in Stack Overflow (and logged into my account) using **Google Chrome (70)** I saw this ad:

> [image]

It says that Apple has 21 open job positions. So I clicked on it and it redirected me to [Apple company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/apple) on Stack Overflow jobs. Naturally I would expect to see those mentioned job positions but for some reason all I can see is some basic info about the company and no actual job listings. This is the bottom of the page:

> [image]

Now I open up an incognito window in Chrome or Firefox (where **I'm not logged** into my Stack Overflow account) and I see this:

> [image]

Now, here's the thing:
If you (Stack Overflow) or the company (Apple) don't want me to see the job listings then **WHY** would you show me an ad that says there are jobs available? This is ridiculous!

P.S: I don't have any Ad blocker installed and this is problem is not caused by a specific browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the listing on the Jobs page is based on your Jobs Preferences, specifically the **"Where you'd like to work"**. I just tried adding "United States" to my preference, and 17 job openings were listed (all in the US).

When not logged-in, SO cannot get this information and thus list all job openings. This might be a valid feature request to see all job openings regardless of the user's preference on job location (perhaps by adding a checkbox to toggle?)

As for the ads... I could only speculate that the ads only check all job openings regardless of user's preference (yeah, kind of contradicting the purpose of the ads, but there might be performance issue... or just a pure bug)

Comment: I can confirm that changing my job preferences fixed the issue however I still think that it shouldn't show me the ads that don't match my preferences and if it does show them, then I should also be allowed to see the full list.

Comment: @VahidAmiri thanks for flagging this. Confirming that what Andrew said above is accurate. Listings are filtered based on your preferences and location across the Jobs site. However, our ads infrastructure is separate and doesn't (yet) account for job preferences the same way the rest of the site does. It's tech debt we're slowly working our way through. Sorry for the confusion this caused, and we'll do our best to improve this experience in the coming year.